# Highcharts 7 - Center an Annotation

Tags: javascript, css, angular, highcharts

I am wanting to have an annotation appear over the top of certain data on my Highchart.  I have added the annotation at the location of my data however it starts from the center of my data point. However I want the annotation to be centered on the Point. See images and Plnkr below.

What I have
[image]

What I want
[image]
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/hHGxXF3pRs7j9M8a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the black line **starts** from the middle of value which you gave; in your case  "1547442017000"; But since we wan't the black line to over come the yellow... you can pull it back, but pulling back by any arbitrary number wouldn't do because the screen size impacts this value;

so we take a **different** approach, we increase the size of the stroke (using the strokeWidth value below), so that the value still points to '1547442017000'... we just increase the stroke size.

[complete working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbvckq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**relevant code**:

```
annotations: [
        {
          shapes: [{
            point: {
              xAxis: 0,
              yAxis: 0,
              x: 1547442017000, y: 1
            },
            type: 'rect',
            height: 355,
            width: 0.01,
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            strokeWidth: 20
          }]
        }]
```

Comment: What a ridiculously awesome answer!!! Exactly what I needed an well explained.

Thanks!

Comment: @Campey, thank you for your kind words, good luck to you on your endeavors